# dictionary returns none when there should be a value python

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a small sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd


df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H578','H600', 'H700'],
  'CD': ['AAAAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCCC','DDDDDD', 'EEEEEEE']}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I read this in with pandas and transform these 2 columns into a dictionary with the 'ID' being the key and 'CD' being the value:

```
dictionary = df.set_index('ID')['CD'].to_dict()
```

because I need to do other things (which i will not go into details, it's a  long story and my actual script is long script that involves many other things) , i need to save the dictionary as value-key pairs, reversed:

```
reversedic = dict()
for key, val in dictionary.items():
        reversedic.pop(val, key)    #python 2.7 uses dic.append() but for the python I have which is 3.5, 'dict' object has no attribute 'append', so is pop the correct code?
```

**later on in my larger script i will need to get the 'ID' when given a 'CD' value**

```
z = reversedic.get('AAAAAAA')
print(z)
```

this should have returned H576  but it returned 'none' instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just directly create the reverse dictionary with pandas, i.e. `reversedic = df.set_index('CD')['ID'].to_dict()`?

Comment: this is a good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not directly:

```
reverseDict = {v:k for k,v in dictionary.iteritems()}

In [14]: reverseDict['AAAAAAA']
Out[14]: 'H576'
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs about dict.pop():

> **pop(key[, default])**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, remove it and return its value, else return default. If default is not given and key is not in the dictionary, a KeyError is raised.

If you want to add a key-value pair to the dictionary, use

```
reversedic[key] = val
```

Comment: This is removng key from dict, not returning key value. Is this what OP wants a shortened dict.

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` returns the value for the `key` passed to it. The second parameter is default value which is returned if `key` is not present in the dictionary.

You can just do :

```
reversedic[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since create first Dict this way

```
dictionary = df.set_index('ID')['CD'].to_dict()
```

Why not?

```
reversedic = df.set_index('CD')['ID'].to_dict()
```

Then:

```
z = reversedic.get('AAAAAAA')
print(z)
```

or

```
z = reversedic['AAAAAAA']
print(z)
```

Comment: this is actually the easiest way  but since my question is asking about a didff. thing, i accepted someone else's answer. thx